# Security concerns regarding unique JWT token in asp.net web api c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jwt

I have created an asp.net MVC web API application which uses JWT token to authorise the users after normal login.

I am able to implement it correctly but I have following concerns regarding security:

1. If someone copies the token of valid user and tries to access the api
   (my current implementation not able to identify it).
2. How to detect if someone logins from two different machines?
3. What are the other things needed to be included in JWT token generation? (I have now used userid in my current implementation)

I need some guidance.

Thanks In advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copying the token is not easy as you will store it in local storage of browser. It will be more secure than stealing cookie.
2. You can add one more claim : Mac Address. Then on each request compare the Mac Address of Request with Mac of Claim.
3. Use a long random string, it should be enough. I would recommend 25 characters as standard. Don't store the key in web.config. Your token is as secure as the secrecy of your key.